# How to get Html::fileInput() value in yii2 Action?

Tags: php, yii2, active-form

I am using `<?= Html::fileInput() ?>` instead of `<?= $form->field($model, 'image_file')->fileInput() ?>` because i haven't passed any model to my form I am using Yii2 active form.

Now My question is that when i post this form how could i access this file in my action. I could see the file attributes using $_FILES variable. but is there any Yii method to access it.

I tried this also:

```
$documentObject = UploadedFile::getInstance(Yii::$app->request->post(), 'image_file');
```

but it is showing this Exception

```
Call to a member function formName() on array
```

Now how to access this file in action

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why i getting an error "Call to a member function formName() on a non-object"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430141/why-i-getting-an-error-call-to-a-member-function-formname-on-a-non-object)

Comment: How could u call it a duplicate, Please read complete question first i am asking about accessing file input. The error msg is same dosen't mean that question is duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work (from [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#getInstanceByName()-detail)):

`$documentObject = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('image_file');`

where `image_file` is your html input's name.